# Changing WinOS windows appearance with ctypes and SetWindowLongPtr

Tags: python

Hello i'm trying change the style of my active window with ctypes and window  API.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

title = "MY CUSTOM WINDOW NAME"
b_string1 = title.encode('utf-8')
Active_W = ctypes.windll.user32.GetActiveWindow()
ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowTextA(Active_W,ctypes.c_char_p(b_string1)) #rename window not working
```

successfully changed the active name.

but

```
import bpy 
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x80 #HIDE 
SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40 #SHOW
SWP_NOMOVE     = 0x0002 #NO MOVE
SWP_NOSIZE     = 0x0001 #NO SIZE
SIZESW_MINIMIZE = 6
SW_RESTORE = 9
GWL_STYLE = -16
GWL_EXSTYLE = -20

title = "0x00200000L"
b_string1 = title.encode('utf-8')
Active_W = ctypes.windll.user32.GetActiveWindow()

ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrA(Active_W,GWL_STYLE,b_string1)
ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(Active_W,-1,2560,60,1000,1000,SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOMOVE)
```

make the window freeze ? none of the different styles work for me, it keep freezing (im doing this from blender by the way, could it be linked ?, or am i doing something wrong ?) sometimes it freeze instantly sometimes it freeze only when i click away from my new window is there any example about SetWindowLongPtr and ctypes ?

from the advices of Ni, i tried

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *


Active_W = ctypes.windll.user32.GetActiveWindow()

SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40 #SHOW
SWP_NOMOVE     = 0x0002 #NO MOVE
GWL_STYLE = -16
GWL_EXSTYLE = -20

EXSTYLE = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrA(Active_W,GWL_EXSTYLE)
STYLE   = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrA(Active_W,GWL_STYLE)

flags = ctypes.c_long(0x00800000|STYLE)
b_string1 = ctypes.byref(flags)

ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrA(Active_W,GWL_STYLE,b_string1) 
ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(Active_W,-1,2560,60,1000,1000,SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOMOVE)
```

it don't freeze anymore, but i don't see the style changing ? 
if i change the EXSTYLE any code tranform the window to this.
[exstyle change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq8Gg.jpg) oe this for any style change [any style change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjHgn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the parameter `b_string1` you are passing to `SetWindowLongPtrA` is completely wrong. The third argument should be the window style, of type `LONG_PTR`, while you pass it a string. Try the following instead:

```
flags = ctypes.c_long(0x00200000L)
b_string1 = ctypes.byref(flags)
```

Also, you should probably use `GetWindowLongPtrA` first to get the current flags and avoid overriding all of them.

Comment: `Error:   File "C:\Users\doria\Desktop\testwin.blend\Text", line 24
    b_string1 = ctypes.byref(0x00200000L)
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` thanks ! but got an error msg

Comment: Try without the `L` at the end of the number

Comment: `TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'int'` it's not working either.

Comment: okay thanks, it still freeze but it must probably be the fault of blender python.

Comment: Did you try using GetWindowLongPtrA and changing only the flag you wanted?

Comment: `print(ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrA(Active_W,GWL_STYLE))` got me `349110272`what am i supposed to do with it ?

Comment: Modify it as you want to, probably using the `|` operator, then use `SetWindowLongPtrA`

Comment: okay i updated the post with your proposition, unfortunatly still not working, either i can't encode the old flag, or it will not consider GetWindowLongPtrA as an "unsupported operand types"

Comment: You are still using a bad `b_string1`

Comment: indeed, i copied the code from a wrong window, i updated the correct code

Comment: You can use `|` on the numbers themselves, not on the byref.

Comment: okay updated the main post with the new proposition. its not freezing anymore but the styles dont work ?